# Can i get facebook checkins of my facebook page with realtime updates api?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-checkins

According to facebook page realtime documentation
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/page/#realtime
it says we can get following things real time updates  with api as a page.

- name
- category_lists
- picture
- checkins
- feed

I have setup my app and page to get real time updates properly. 
Here is my app setting screen shot for realtime updates. 
[image]

Here is my code to receive and store request to database. I am using codeigniter framework.

```
  define('VERIFY_TOKEN', 'krishna');
    $method = $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'];

    if ($method == 'GET' && $_GET['hub_mode'] == 'subscribe' && $_GET['hub_verify_token'] == VERIFY_TOKEN) {
        echo $_GET['hub_challenge'];
    } else if ($method == 'POST') {

        if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_HUB_SIGNATURE'])) {
            $post_body = file_get_contents("php://input");
            $d['val'] = $post_body;
            $this->db->insert('facebook', $d);

        }
    }
```

Here i m  getting all the updates like feed, picture etc. But i m not getting checkins update. Is it possible to get checkin update with real time api or the documentation is fake?

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be a documentation bug in the FB docs. Instead of enabling 'checkins' for the subscription, you must enable 'feed'.  Then user checkins will appear at your callback url as changed_fields=feed
Then you can read the user's feed and match the timestamp in the RTU and/or look for status updates with a location/place.